# Getting the string out of a string

Tags: javascript, html

I am having  a string as:

```
var Str = "&nbsp;text";
```

I want only "text" out of Str.
My output should be:
 Str = "text" from " text" 
 how can I get the output i am expecting from the given String

Comment: What have you tried so far? I'm assuming you're not just looking for the output "text" in your actual application so what criteria determine which parts of the string should be extracted?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the size or structure of the string then i suggest you use 
var Str = str.substring(6);

Answer (score 0):

```
var Str = "&nbsp;text";
Str = Str.replace(/&nbsp;/g, '');
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
if (!String.prototype.decodeHtml) {
    String.prototype.decodeHtml = function () {
        return this.replace(/&amp;/g, '&')
            .replace(/&lt;/g, '<')
            .replace(/&gt;/g, '>')
            .replace(/&quot;/g, '"');// "
    };
}
var Str = "&nbsp;text".decode();
```

If you don't like messing with the prototype, you can of course just use it as an ordinary function.